# Sending a reply draft using Gmail API results in "Invalid draft" error

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail, gmail-api, reply

I'm trying to send a reply to the first (original) message of a thread using the **Gmail API** in Apps Script. The code successfully creates a draft with the reply content, but when attempting to send the draft using Gmail.Users.Drafts.send(), I receive an "Invalid draft" error. I should also add that I previously tried Gmail.app method and it only sends the reply to the sender of the first message (me).

Here's the relevant code snippet:

```
    var thread = GmailApp.getThreadById(existingThreadId); 
 var messages = thread.getMessages();
// Retrieve the original message
var originalMessage = messages[0];
var recipientEmail = originalMessage.getTo();
var senderEmail = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();

// Create a draft reply
var draftReplyRequestBody = {
  message: {
    threadId: existingThreadId,
    raw: Utilities.base64EncodeWebSafe("Test Test Test"),
    payload: {
      headers: [
        { name: "Reply-To", value: recipientEmail } // Add the Reply-To header with the recipient email address
      ]
    }
  }
};

var draftReplyResponse = Gmail.Users.Drafts.create(draftReplyRequestBody, "me");
var draftReplyId = draftReplyResponse.id;

// Send the draft reply using Gmail API
var sendReplyParams = {
  userId: "me",
  draftId: draftReplyId
};

// Log the email body and thread ID for verification
console.log('Email Body:', draftReplyRequestBody);
console.log('Thread ID:', existingThreadId);
console.log('Draft Reply ID:', draftReplyId);

Gmail.Users.Drafts.send(sendReplyParams, "me");
```

I have verified that the values for recipientEmail, existingThreadId, and draftReplyRequestBody are correct by logging them. However, when executing the Gmail.Users.Drafts.send() function, I encounter the "Invalid draft" error:

**"GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to gmail.users.drafts.send failed with error: Invalid draft"**

I have also checked the documentation and made sure that the required properties are set, such as the threadId and raw content encoded in base64 web-safe format.

Could someone please help me identify what could be causing this "Invalid draft" error and provide guidance on how to resolve it?

Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- In your script, I thought of the following modification.

  - In this case, please use `raw` of the web-safe base64 encoded data including "From", "To", "Subject", "Body".
  - The request body of `sendReplyParams` is not correct. I thought that the reason for your current issue of `GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to gmail.users.drafts.send failed with error: Invalid draft` might be due to this.

When these points are reflected in your script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
var thread = GmailApp.getThreadById(existingThreadId);
var messages = thread.getMessages();
var originalMessage = messages[0];
var recipientEmail = originalMessage.getTo();
var senderEmail = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
var messageId = originalMessage.getHeader("Message-ID");
var data = [
  "MIME-Version: 1.0\n",
  `In-Reply-To: ${messageId}\n`,
  `Subject: Re:${originalMessage.getSubject()}\n`,
  `From: ${senderEmail}\n`,
  `To: ${recipientEmail}\n\n`,
  "Test Test Test",
].join("");
var draftReplyRequestBody = {
  message: {
    threadId: existingThreadId,
    raw: Utilities.base64EncodeWebSafe(data),
  }
};
var draftReplyResponse = Gmail.Users.Drafts.create(draftReplyRequestBody, "me");
var draftReplyId = draftReplyResponse.id;
var sendReplyParams = { id: draftReplyId };
console.log('Email Body:', draftReplyRequestBody);
console.log('Thread ID:', existingThreadId);
console.log('Draft Reply ID:', draftReplyId);
Gmail.Users.Drafts.send(sendReplyParams, "me");
```

- When this script is run, an email is replied to `existingThreadId` by preparing a draft.
- In this modification, it supposes that the values of `senderEmail`, `recipientEmail` are valid values. Please be careful about this.
- From your following reply,

  > I tried this , although I changed the "getFrom();" in line for to "getTo();" because I wanna send a reply to a message which has been sent by me to other one. It worked fine but there is a problem. Recipient received that reply as a separate email and not appended to the thread as a reply. ( the recipient is using gmail too). how to modify the code in order to quote the original message of the thread and send a reply as gmail UI?

  - I updated the above script.

#### References:

- [Method: users.drafts.create](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.drafts/create)
- [Method: users.drafts.send](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.drafts/send)

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. I tried this , although I changed the "getFrom();" in line for to "getTo();" because I wanna send a reply to a message which has been sent by me to other one.  It worked fine but there is a problem.  Recipient received that reply as a separate email and not appended to the thread as a reply. ( the recipient is using gmail too). how to modify the code in order to quote the original message of the thread and send a reply as gmail UI?

Comment: @Hamed Thank you for replying. From `Thank you very much for your response. I tried this , although I changed the "getFrom();" in line for to "getTo();" because I wanna send a reply to a message which has been sent by me to other one. It worked fine`, I understood that your showing error in your question was resolved.

Comment: @Hamed About your new issue of `but there is a problem. Recipient received that reply as a separate email and not appended to the thread as a reply. ( the recipient is using gmail too). how to modify the code in order to quote the original message of the thread and send a reply as gmail UI?`, I updated my modified script. But, I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your new issue. So, please confirm it. If I misunderstood your new issue, I apologize.

Comment: OMG! I greatly appreciate your brilliant response, Tanaike. You are awesome and fantastic. It worked completely and properly. Now, it sends the reply in the same thread. It works properly in the Gmail platform when the sender and receiver are using Gmail. I sent the reply to a recipient on another email platform, although it is ok to receive it as a separate email ( it does not support threading),  the body of the email only contains the reminder text and not quoted the original message and attachments. I mean how can we replicate the Gmail UI reply?

Comment: for example like this: 

<sender@gmail.com>

to : <recipient@example.com

I just want to followup my previous email. Regards

On Fri, Jul 7, 2023 at 3:21 PM <sender@gmail.com> wrote:
Test Test Test

Comment: @Hamed Thank you for replying. About `OMG! I greatly appreciate your brilliant response, Tanaike. You are awesome and fantastic. It worked completed and properly. Now, it sends the reply in the same thread. It works properly in the Gmail platform when the sender and receiver are using Gmail. I sent the reply to a recipient on another email platform,`, I understood that your new issue was resolved.

Comment: @Hamed About your 2nd new issue of `although it is ok to receive it as a separate email ( it does not support threading), the body of email only contains the reminder text. I mean how can we replicate the Gmail UI reply?`, I would like to support you. But, it is different from your 1st question. So can you post it as new question?

Comment: I am sorry about it. You are right. I am closing this question and I will post the new issue about quoting the original message and replicating the Gmail UI reply as a new question. I would appreciate your help with the new issue if you could check it.

Comment: @Hamed Thank you for your response. When I saw your new question, I would like to check it. When I found a solution, I would like to post it as an answer.